# Naming convention for buffer solutions/systems

Tags: acid-base, ph

Is there an official naming convention to follow for buffer solutions/systems? I've noticed that the name of the buffer usually just follows the name of the salt (ex. sodium acetate buffer), but what if the buffer is diprotic?

If I mixed tartaric acid with its double salt, potassium sodium tartrate, would the resulting buffer simply be "potassium sodium tartrate buffer"? Or would it be something like "bitartrate-tartrate buffer"?

Comment: I cannot say it is official, but the historical convention is to use the buffer name in sense of the general term for all forms of the buffering substance. E.g. phosphate in the wider sense is the general term for all salts of $\ce{H3PO4}$ ( in even wider sense also for polyphosphates, like in enviromental chemistry).       The particular  buffer active forms are implicitly defined by pH range or the particular value. E.g. the phosphate buffer for $\mathrm{p}H=6.8$  does not contain $\ce{PO4^3-}$ as a major component, but $\ce{H2PO4^-}$ and $\ce{HPO4^2-}$